# CSS grid support for autoprefixer on webpack

Tags: css, webpack, internet-explorer-11, css-grid, postcss

I am using autoprefixer with postcss and webpack for a project.  I am also using CSS grid.  However, I've noticed when I build my code the ms prefixes for css grid does not work.

Here is my postcss.config.js which is working for things such as flexbox.

How do I enable CSS grid support?

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, autoprefixer doesn't prefix grid properties.

See the [autoprefixer documentation:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer)

> Autoprefixer has 4 features, which can be enabled or disabled by
>   options:
>
> ...
>
> grid: true will enable Grid Layout prefixes for IE.

The syntax for setting [options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer#options) would look something like:

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const plugin = autoprefixer({ grid: true });
module.exports = { plugins: [ plugin ] }
```

---

That being said, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/CSS_Grid_and_Progressive_Enhancement#Autoprefixer_grid_layout_support) has this to say about autoprefixer for grid properties:

> The popular tool autoprefixer has been updated to support the -ms-
>   grid version when you use the new grid properties. Unless your layout
>   is very simple line-based placement, this is likely to cause you more
>   problems that it solves. I would not suggest letting autoprefixer run
>   on grid properties, and instead write a version using the IE version
>   of Grid Layout, if it makes sense for you.

Additionally, Rachel Andrew wrote [a thorough post](https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/) on this topic

In that post she notes the following:

> ...even where similar properties exist in the two versions of the
>   specification, the capabilities of the older spec and implementation
>   are very different to the new one. This means you can’t simply run
>   Autoprefixer and consider the job done.

Comment: would you write like this? const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const plugin = autoprefixer({ grid: true });

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    plugin
  ]
}

Comment: You are the best !! :) Thank you !! :)